# SQL join excluding null values

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find the min year of the model aircraft 737
I am getting null values in the year column

```
SELECT m.name
     , m.n_number
     , m.mfr_mdl_code
     , MIN(m.year_mfr) min_year
     , a.model
     , a.code
  FROM master m
  JOIN acftref a
    ON m.mfr_mdl_code = a.code
 WHERE a.model = 737
 ORDER
    BY m.year_mfr IS NOT NULL
 LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Have you tried putting your "is not null" condition on the where?  Because I don't think it will help as part of the ORDER clause.

Comment: `where acftref.model = 737 && acftref.year_mfr is not null order by master.year_mfr limit 10`

Comment: This appears to be a version of the GROUPWISE MAX problem, the single most frequently asked question under the MySQL tag. But if after reviewing similar questions you're still struggling, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the restriction on your date field. Try the following:

```
select master.name
,master.n_number
,master.mfr_mdl_code
,min(master.year_mfr) as min_year
,acftref.model
,acftref.code
from master
join acftref on master.mfr_mdl_code=acftref.code
where acftref.model=737
and master.year_mfr is not null
order by master.year_mfr
limit 10;
```

Comment: I think there's more to it than that!

Comment: I have tried adding the where master.year_mfr is not null.

Comment: I also tried taking out the MIN and just ordering by master.year_mfr desc